# Electronic configuration of excited states

Tags: electronic-configuration

> Fill the following table:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{lccr}
> \hline
> \text{Electronic configuration} & \text{Term} & J & E/\pu{cm^-1} \\
> \hline
> [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{(3s)^2(3p)^5}   &     &     &     0 \\
>                                  &     &     &   881 \\
> \hline
> [\ce{Ne}]\mathrm{(3s)^2(3p)^44s} &     &     & 71954 \\
>                                  &     &     & 72484 \\
>                                  &     &     & 72823 \\
>                                  & ^2D & 5/2 & 74221 \\
>                                  &     & 3/2 & 74861 \\
>                                  & ^2P & 3/2 & 84116 \\
>                                  &     & 1/2 & 84127 \\
>                                  & ^2S & 1/2 & 88351 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

My questions are:

1. How do I compute the electronic configuration of the excited levels in general and in this case?
2. I know that when taking into account the spin-orbit interaction, the quantum number $l$ is no longer a good number, however we always use the notation with S, P, D, … orbitals, which corresponds to $l = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ Does this mean that an electron can "move" between different values of $l$ although the occupied states with those values of $l$ remain the same?

Comment: *"we always use the notation with S, P, D.. orbitals"* That's not exactly right; the big letters S,P,D have not much to do with s, p, and d orbitals (small letters). Big letters denote the quantum number $L$ which reflects the total angular momentum of all the electrons, not the quantum number $l$ which reflects the angular momentum of one individual electron. Put another way: big letters describe the electronic state of the atom. Small letters describe the state of one individual electron.

Comment: Thank you very much! And is L a good number regardless of the spin-orbit interaction then?

Comment: Hmm, if your spin-orbit interaction is very strong (heavy atoms), then $L$ isn't good anymore. For small atoms it's good enough. The reason why term symbols use $L$ and not individual $l$ is not because of spin-orbit coupling (that couples orbital AM and spin AM). It's because of coupling between the orbital AM of different electrons. The steps are: (1) couple all the electron spins $s$ to form one total spin $S$; (2) couple all the electron orbital AM $l$ to form one total orbital AM $L$; (3) and then couple $S$ and $L$ to get the total AM $J$. The term symbol is then $^{2S+1}L_J$.

Comment: thank you so much, this clarifies a lot.